ASCII art probleme
I'd like your help with a program that processes text in ASCII art.
The program must write a letter or a word in the ASCII style given as input.
The problem is that the program returns me at the end all the time the letter "A" written in the ASCII style.
Could you take a look and tell me what you think?
Code :
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read the length (L) of the ASCII style
        int L = in.nextInt();

        // Read the height (H) of the ASCII style
        int H = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine(); // Pour consommer la ligne vide

        // Read the word to be displayed in ASCII style
        String T = in.nextLine();

        // Read the ASCII Style
        StringBuilder styleBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            String ROW = in.nextLine();
            styleBuilder.append(ROW).append("\n");
        }
        String style = styleBuilder.toString();

        // Display the word using the ASCII style provided        
        String[] lines = style.split("\n");
        int lineCount = lines.length;
        int wordLength = T.length();
        int letterWidth = wordLength * L;// Each letter is assumed to occupy L characters
        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
            StringBuilder printedLine = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < letterWidth; j++) {
                int letterIndex = j / L; // Each letter occupies L characters
                char c = (letterIndex < wordLength) ? T.charAt(letterIndex) : ' '; 
                int index = j % L; // Hint in ASCII style line
                printedLine.append(lines[i].charAt(index));
            }
            System.out.println(printedLine);
        }
    }
}


I think that I don't understand your comments, maybe wanna translate them into english?

@Slevin sure i gonna translate the comments now

It doesn't really work like that. What you're trying to do is write Unix banner in Java. That works by default with a grid of 6x8 (wxh), where the top and bottom 'rows' are empty. Here's a demo of writing the letter A:
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final int[][] A = {  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },  { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 },  { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 },  { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },  { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },  { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },  { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };

        for(int[] row : A) {
           for (int v : row) {
               if (v == 1) {
                   System.out.print('#');
               }
               else {
                   System.out.print(' ');
               }
           }
           System.out.println();    
        }
    }
}


In the old days where one coded glyphs for the C64, bits represented the actual dots. Would make much more fun for this example as well, besides being more readable^^ since one could spot the glyph through 0b00011000, just 2 cents from a fan...

@Slevin, yes. That's a nice idea. Though the subsequent bit manipulation might be tricky for a less advanced programmer.

Yes, but much to learn in a playful manner, best way to practice. And the question itself seems to come out of a curious challenge anyway, thus to the OP: Go for it and have a nice weekend.

@g00se  Thank you for taking the time to reply! In fact I'm trying to solve this problem because it comes from a site with daily challenges and the problem I'm encountering is that when I enter a word to have it output with the desired ASCII style the program returns the letter "A" written in the requested style every time. This makes me think that the problem is the word storage, I've tried several tricks but nothing works for the moment : (

You'll need to explain how your approach is meant to work. Remember, ASCII art prints characters as 'pixels' to represent characters
